# Find missing values in NumPy array of dtype obj

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, nan

I'm being driven crazy by a NumPy array of dtype `obj` with a missing value (in the example below, it is the penultimate value).

```
>> a
array([0, 3, 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', 'male', 22.0, 1, 0, 'A/5 21171',
       7.25, nan, 'S'], dtype=object)
```

I want to find this missing value programatically with a function that returns a boolean vector with `True` values in elements that correspond to missing values in the array (as per the example below).

```
>> some_function(a)
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False],
      dtype=bool)
```

I tried `isnan` to no avail.

```
>> isnan(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not
be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I also attempted performing the operation explicitly over every element of the array with `apply_along_axis`, but the same error is returned.

```
>> apply_along_axis(isnan, 0, a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not
be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Can anyone explain to me (1) what I'm doing wrong and (2) what I can do to solve this problem? From the error, I gather that it has to do with one of the elements not being in an appropriate type. What is the easiest way to get around this issue?

Comment: I don't think you can 'nan' an object

Comment: You mean `isnan` an object?

Comment: If the `nan`s you're looking for are confined to that column, you could slice or index the array before applying `isnan`. You might also consider a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) rather than an object array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another workaround is:

```
In [148]: [item != item for item in a]
Out[148]: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False]
```

since [NaNs are not equal to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/190597). Note, however, that it is possible to define custom objects which, like NaN, are not equal to themselves:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __cmp__(self, obj):
        return -1
foo = Foo()
assert foo != foo
```

so using `item != item` does not necessarily mean `item` is a NaN.

---

Note that it is generally a good idea to avoid NumPy arrays of dtype `object` if possible.

- They are not particularly quick -- operations on its contents
  generally devolve into Python calls on the underlying Python objects. A normal
  Python list often has better performance.
- Unlike numeric arrays which can be more space efficient than a Python list of numbers, object arrays are not particularly space efficient since every item is a
  reference to a Python object.
- They are also not particular convenient since many NumPy operations
  do not work on arrays of dtype `object`. `isnan` is one such example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just curious, if you don't recommend NumPy arrays of dtype `object`, what do you suggest to store mixed data (i.e., numeric and string)?

Comment: I would use a Python list or tuple instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! List comprehension is the way to go.

The problem arises from the fact that `isnan` cannot be called on strings. Therefore, the trick is to iterate through the elements, performing the `isnan` operation on any elements that are NOT of the type string.

```
[isnan(i) if type(i) != str else False for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Pandas.isna`. Unlike the corresponding function in lumpy, this version handles missing string values.

```
s = np.array(['one', 'two', None, 'four'])
pd.isna(s)
```

The output:

```
array([False, False,  True, False])
```